# Capistrano Install and Mac folder permissions

Tags: permissions, installation, capistrano

I recently got a new MacBook Pro and I am trying to install Capistrano on it.  When run "gem install capistrano" I get errors having to do with folder permissions even though I am the Admin on the computer.
The first time I got "Permission denied - /library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.15".  I then went into that folder's info screen and changed the permissions to allow access.  The next time I ran "gem install capistrano" it gave me the error "you don't have write permissions into the /usr/bin directory".

Why am i getting these errors if I'm logged in as the admin? Admittedly I'm a noob at this, but I don't want to keep manually changing folder permissions after each error so I was wondering if there was anything I could do here to avoid future problems... thanks.

running: OSX 10.8.2  ruby 1.8.7

**UPDATE:** I tried repairing the disk permissions and it basically undid the manual permissions switching I had done after the first error.  I kinda expected that... so the problem still persists...

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after asking around a bit...

Use the "super user do" command "sudo" before the "gem install" command.  It will ask for your password, enter it and you're good to go.  So I ran "sudo gem install capistrano" and it worked fine.  Hope this helps another noob like me out some day.....

Comment: I am a noob and this did help, thanks for posting the followup!